# Issue while revoking app permission from application Settings in Android

Tags: android, kotlin, permissions, android-permissions, user-permissions

The issue is while the app is running,
I am pressing the settings icon and navigate to Application settings screen,

there I am just revoking the permission (Location permission) or pressed on 'Deny' button.

Now, Since the app is in recent mode when I open the app from the recent mode, My app UI getting mismatched with fragments.

**NOTE : This is working fine If the app is killed and If I try to revoke permission from the Settings**.

And I am getting below exceptions :

> ```
> 2021-11-19 15:20:24.637 16474-16474/ W/.: Accessing hidden method
> ```
>
> Ljava/lang/Thread;->init2(Ljava/lang/Thread;)V (greylist-max-o,
> linking, denied) 2021-11-19 15:20:24.637
> 16474-16474/ W/.: Accessing hidden
> field Ljava/lang/Thread;->contextClassLoader:Ljava/lang/ClassLoader;
> (greylist, linking, allowed) 2021-11-19 15:20:24.650
> 16474-16474/W/: Accessing hidden
> method
> Landroid/app/LoadedApk;->getServiceDispatcherCommon(Landroid/content/ServiceConnection;Landroid/content/Context;Landroid/os/Handler;Ljava/util/concurrent/Executor;I)Landroid/app/IServiceConnection;
> (blacklist, linking, denied) 2021-11-19 15:20:24.637
> 16474-16474/ W/ Accessing hidden
> method
> Ljava/lang/ThreadLocal;->createInheritedMap(Ljava/lang/ThreadLocal$ThreadLocalMap;)Ljava/lang/ThreadLocal$ThreadLocalMap;
> (greylist-max-o, linking, denied)
> What might be the issue?

Comment: Weird that it would crash since revoking any permission should forcefully kill your app process either way. Still you haven't provided any context as to how you're using location permission (activity? service? framework or an api?) so don't expect people to guess the solution.

Comment: @Pawel I am checking and granting permission in my HomeActivity. When I revoked the permission the last activity which is open is coming for recreation (HomeActivity) and the flow is normal when activity recreate - i.e. onCreate, onStart, onResume() etc. this is fine. But, How can I know that permission is revoked from the settings and I have to clear the older allocated resources of the Activity ? 
Hope you understood what the issue is - and that's the reason that my fragments inside Homeactivity get clusttered on each other (couple of fragments)
Is there any way to clear activity resoures?

Comment: By design you should never assume permissions are granted forever and check them at least once per component lifecycle (once per on create). I don't understand what allocated resources you have in mind, if you're persisting the fact that permission was granted beyond `onDestroy` and use it to assume it still is after its recreated that's an error.

Comment: As I have mentioned the issue is not with the permission but the with UI - fragments got overlapped. I am posting solution. It's simple.. checkout after some time.

Comment: How could anyone have helped with your UI when you haven't posted a single line of code

Comment: It's a logical quetion sir. Hope you can understand. Added Solution.

Answer (score 0):

When we come back to our App or resume after revoking the permission from the setting,
The last Activity will be created again i.e. starts from the onCreate() method.

So, to resolve this issue we can do one thing :
We can check inside onCreate() method that isSavedInstanceState is null or not?

If it's not null then we can simply finish() the current activity and start the Splash activity (This is the ideal behaviour in any android app)

Solution :

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    try{
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            startActivity(
                Intent(this@AppActivity, SplashActivity::class.java)
                    .addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK or Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK)
            )
            finish()
        }else{
           //do your stuff - navigate to home activity
        }
    }catch(e:Exception)
    {
        e.printStackTrace()
    }
}
```